# Flexslider prev/next not working in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, navigation, flexslider

I am developing the WordPress theme.. For purpose i try to integrate Flexslider on my theme.. but the next/previous button(arrow) doesn't work at chrome browser.. but it works well in all other browsers.. Can Anyone know about issue !!.. please give me a solution...

```
jQuery('.flexslider').flexslider({
    animation: "fade",
    direction: "horizontal",
    slideshowSpeed: ani_speed,
    animationSpeed: trans_speed,
    slideshow: autoplay,
    touch: true,
});
```

this my jQuery ...

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this question been answered before "[Flexslider manualControls not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15246994/flexslider-manualcontrols-not-working/29123090#29123090)", i've had the same problem, it was due to having touch events enabled in the 'chrome://flags' page of chrome, after turning off in settings the flexslider navigation arrows and dots will work.